# iText - add digits with text when converting html to pdf

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I am using iText with `RTL` font like this [example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-set-rtl-direction-hebrew-when-converting-html-pdf).

It works fine but when the text has digits or other chars like `/:()` the digits and chars are not displayed in the pdf, here is my html:

```
<div dir="rtl" style="font-family: Noto Sans Hebrew;border: 5px solid blue;font-weight: bold;position:relative;bottom:70px">תאריך 18.10.2010
</div>
```

Converting the same way as the example:

```
public void createPdf(String file, String htmlString, String pathToTTF)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
            new FileOutputStream(file));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    // Styles
    CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(
            XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS); //
    fontProvider.register(pathToTTF);
    CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

    // Pipelines
    PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(new FileInputStream(htmlString), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

And the oputput:

```
תאריך
```

Thanks for any help.